# Using context in KMM shared library (Manually)

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I am building a common library module in KMM that requires android application context.

How can I pass it to common module manually?

I have seen answers using `androidx.startup.InitializationProvider` which requires separate dependency.

I don't want any dependency.

Comment: You can’t use android application context in common source set of your shared library. It is platform specific code, you should place it in android source set. Could you share more context what you are going to implement?

Comment: I am building a KMM library which is going to have an initialising method like `MyLib.init(context, secret_key)` I need context for many purpose. First of all is SQLite database initialisation then others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a good solution using `expect`/`actual` mechanism of `object`.

1. Create an expect object in commonMain

```
expect object AppContext
```

2. Create actual object in androidMain

```
import android.content.Context
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference

actual object AppContext {

    private var value: WeakReference<Context?>? = null

    fun set(context: Context) {
        value = WeakReference(context)
    }

    internal fun get(): Context? {
        return value?.get()
    }

}
```

3. Leave iOS AppContext empty as we don't need context there

```
actual object AppContext
```

4. Create another class in commonMain

```
class MyLibConfig(
    val appContext: AppContext,
    val isTestDevice: Boolean = false,
    val isLogsEnabled: Boolean = false,
)
```

5. Create your commonMain public API object

```
object MyLib {
    fun initialize(config: MyLibConfig) {
        val commonContext = config.appContext
    }
}
```

6. Pass this context to your native platform specific methods as argument. For example

```
override fun getMyLibDatabase(appContext: AppContext): SqlDriver {
        return AndroidSqliteDriver(
            my_lib_db.Schema,
            appContext.get()!!,
            "my_lib_db.sqlite"
        )
    }
```

7. Initialize your library from ViewModel or Application class. Much more clear way

```
MyLib.initialize(
            MyLibConfig(
                appContext = AppContext.apply { set(application.applicationContext) },
                isTestDevice = true,
                isLogsEnabled = true,
            )
        )
```

Comment: Seems to me like @Alex neatly answered your question, you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 3):

We can get the Android context using **Koin** in the shared module.

**Initialise the Koin from the Android application or activity class.**

```
initKoin {
    androidLogger()
    androidContext(applicationContext)
}
```

**Now inside the androidMain package of the shared module get the context**

```
actual fun createDriver(): SqlDriver {
    val context: Context = getKoin().get()
    return AndroidSqliteDriver(AppDatabase.Schema, context, "cache.db")
}
```

For the Koin integration please check the [official documentation](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-mp/kmp/)

Answer (score 2):

As you're building a multiplatform library, and `Context` is an Android-specific detail, it's not possible to refer to it in the `commonMain` source set.

As a solution, it's possible to declare your library's functionality under `commonMain` as:

```
interface MyLib {

  fun featureA()

  fun featureB()
}

// This method is a way to get platform-specific implementation of your library
expect fun getMyLib(): MyLib
```

Then, `androidMain` source set is a place where `Context`-dependent implementation should go. For example:

```
class AndroidMyLib(private val context: Context): MyLib {

  override fun featureA() {
    //context is accessible
  }

  ...
}

actual fun getMyLib() = AndroidMyLib(context)
```

Please note that an iOS-specific implementation of `MyLib` would be needed under `iosMain` as well.

More info on the `expect` / `actual` mechanism of dealing with platform details is in [the KMP docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-connect-to-apis.html).

Comment: As we're not receiving context from getMyLib so how we can pass it to the AndroidMyLib to instantiate the class ? And also we can't add the context in the expect function signature as context is android platform related.